# sorting all data on multiple pages by clicking on its header

Tags: angularjs, list, sorting, header, clicking

i want to sort all results by clicking on its header of column, Actually I took reference from code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjkcg which is working fine but only difference is that i have multiple pages for displaying data so when I used that solution it is sorting the data only on current page not on all the pages. so what i need to change in following code if i want to sort whole data

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span class="label">Ordered By: {{orderByField}}, Reverse Sort: {{reverseSort}}</span><br><br>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          First Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'firstName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='lastName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            Last Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'lastName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='age'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          Age <span ng-show="orderByField == 'age'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>


var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.orderByField = 'firstName';
  $scope.reverseSort = false;

  $scope.data = {
    employees: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      age: 30
    },{
      firstName: 'Frank',
      lastName: 'Burns',
      age: 54
    },{
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'Banter',
      age: 21
    }]
  };
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution